# How to use application gateway in the middle of an architecture and not exposed to the internet

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have an architecture that I want to implement in azure. I have three different webapps, the first one is used as UI, which I am implementing before it an application gateway with public frontend IP. The second webapp is the webserver which I want to place before it another application gateway. I didn't know what frontend IP to put for.
Can I get some help, please.[image]

Comment: Can't you create application gateway with a private frontend ip? I see it's possible for `standard` & `WAF` SKUs.

Comment: the private frontend IP has to be specific right? because I tried to put the inbound IP address of the webserver and it showed me an error that it is not in the same range of the subnet addresses of the application gateway